# Need help downgrading .NET version

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, downgrade

I need to make some modifications to a huge application that runs under .NET 4.5.2.

I installed it on a machine that has later .NET frameworks installed and tried to install 4.5.2 and get the following message: ".NET Framework 4.5.2 or a later update is already installed on this computer."

So then I uninstalled all the .NET frameworks with Control Panel | Uninstall a program, and also with the Visual Studio Installer.  But I still get the same message when I try to install 4.5.2.

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/troubleshoot-blocked-installations-and-uninstallations?redirectedfrom=MSDN, if the Registry key Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full is missing, .NET 4.5 or above isn't installed.  It IS present on my system and can't be changed in Regedit.

So, my question is, how can I remove the last remnants of .NET frameworks so I can install 4.5.2?

Thanks!

Comment: Is app not working, refuse to install or what is the problem, due to which you decide to uninstall newer framework?

Comment: You are [not alone](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+uninstall+.net+framework+site:stackoverflow.com), but there is a [tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/uninstall-tool), worth to try first.

Comment: @Sinatr: The app is designed to run under version 4.5.2, and any other version may introduce uncertainties.

Comment: You shouldn't start uninstalling things if you haven't performed enough research to understand the situation. I recommend you perform more research about .NET Framework versions prior to making any additional changes.